# How to convert from one co-ordinate system to another (graphics)

Tags: graphics, coordinate-systems, perspective

I've been having issues with this for a little while now. I feel like I should know this but I can't for the life of me remember.

How can I map the screen pixels to their respective 'graphical' x,y positions? The co-ordinate systems have been configured to start at the bottom left (0,0) and increase to the top-right.

I want to be able to zoom, so I know that I need to configure the zoom distance into the answer.

```
Screen
|\          Some Quad
| \--------|\Qx
|  \    Z  | \
|   \       \|Qy
 \  |
Sx\ |Sy
   \|
```

I want to know which pixels on my screen will have the quad on it. Obviously as Z decreases, the quad will occupy more of the screen, and as Z increases it will occupy less, but how exactly are these calculated?

For further clarification, I want to know how I can map these screen pixels onto the 'graphical' co-ordinates using the zoom factor into the equation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 for pretty impressive ASCII axes - I did a double take, and sure enough they were what I thought they were!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the zoom factor as a multiplier against the coordinates and/or screen size.

For example, if you have a 100x150 pixel square, when zoomed in to 150%, the size of the rectangle should be 150x225.

An equation for this is:

> h = height
>
> w = width
>
> z = percent zoom
>   (100% = 1.00)
>
> ---
>
> new width =  **W = wz**
>
> new height = **H = hz**

To map screen pixels, apply more basic mathematical principles.  The relative coordinates depend entirely on the center of the zoom.  This is very easy, if everything zooms in the exact center.  If zooming from elsewhere (e.g. stretching the object from a corner or a non-central coordinate), you must apply an offset to your equation.

Zooming a rectangle from its center point is easy.  Divide the difference in rectangle width by 2, and then add it to the left and right coordinate value (you can add a negative number).  Do the same for height.

If zooming the rectangle from a coordinate that is NOT in its exact center, but is still within the bounds of the rectangle, requires an offset.  Simply determine what percentage of height and width change should be applied to each side of the rectangle.  Sides in closer proximity to the zoom point will receive a lower percentage of the change.

When the zoom point resides outside the rectangle, the distance from the zoom point must also be taken into account.  This offset moves the entire rectangle, in addition to scaling the rectangle.

Get a large piece of paper and draw up some visualizations. That always helps. =)

Comment: I think I know why I've struggled so much; the problem is I don't know any of the mapping at all. I know that zooming in will multiply the co-ordinates, and I'm okay with zooming within the same co-ordinate set. The problem is more to do with mapping from my overall screen pixels (offsets already applied for scrolling) onto the quads.

Comment: It seems that if you are unable to determine the coordinates, you are also unable to determine the dimensions of the rectangle.  No matter what the Z value, you are unable to calculate a result without knowing some information about size and positioning.  I suppose you could always zoom from the origin (0,0), which means you only need to worry about a height and width value.  However, there is no way to determine any maximum size limit, if you need one.

Comment: I do know the co-ordinates of both sets of grids, but how this is mapped is causing the issue. Perhaps I can rephrase: graphical co-ordinates of (0,0)(2,0)(2,2)(0,2) make a square. I then set the viewport to Z=-8 which shows the square relatively small in the middle of the screen. If I then get the screen co-ordinates of the top-middle of the square, it might be say 265,220 (widescreen display) how do I map those screen co-ordinates back to the top-middle of my square (in this case (1,2))?

Comment: Figured it out that I needed to use the aspect ratio of the screen (which is the graphical co-ords when Z=0) coupled with the zoom and then divide that by the screen height and width respectively. This gives the amount of 'graphical' co-ords per 1 pixel. This can then be multiplied by the absolute pixel co-ord to the correct location.

Comment: There you go!  It just takes time for the pieces to fall into place. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If (xk, yk) is the center before zooming and the size is (Sx, Sy), zoomed to a factor of Z in (0, 1], the new size will be (Qx, Qy) = (Sx*(1-Z), Sy*(1-Z)) centered on (xk, yk) which means the screen coordinates are:

```
rectangle: xk - Qx/2, yk - Qy/2, xk + Qx/2, yk + Qy/2
```

Hope that helps.